# How do you get SQL to add a variable to a field name in a where clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working with MS-Access. I have a table I am modifying, the fields of the table are:

```
NumberOfCycles, s1,s2,s3,s4...s8
```

the rows have different numbers of s's in them, some have all eight and some have less (the number of s's is specified by NumberOfCycles).  The way the table is now I have redundant data so I'll have something like this.

```
NumberOfCycles, s1,s2,s3,s4...s8  
       4        1   0  1  0  
       4        0   1  0  
       4        1   0  
       4        0
```

I only want the first row.  I tried to solve this by adding a statement to my where clause:

```
where 's' + NumberOfCycles <> Null
```

This doesn't work because SQL just compares the string 's4' with null.  How can I have it so it compares the value of the field s4 (or whatever value of NumberOfCycles) with Null?

Comment: are you just trying to look at the last field?  So if NumberOfCycles is 5 - you are looking at field (column) s5?

Comment: You could write a little VBA, but your table design seems quite strange.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to look at the field equal to the NumberOfCycles.

My table design is strange because I've pulled the raw data from data in a strange format.

Comment: So how about a Union query to normalize things a bit, then query the union query?

Comment: "I have a table I am modifying,"  Don't do that.  Add a table so s1 ... s8 are different rows in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard SQL:

```
WHERE
     CASE NumberOfCycles
          WHEN 1 THEN s1
          WHEN 2 THEN s2
          WHEN 3 THEN s3
          WHEN 4 THEN s4
          WHEN 5 THEN s5
          WHEN 6 THEN s6
          WHEN 7 THEN s7
          WHEN 8 THEN s8
          ELSE NULL
     END IS NOT NULL  -- Can't use <> for NULL
```

For MS Access I believe that this would be:

```
WHERE
     SWITCH(NumberOfCycles=1, s1, NumberOfCycles=2, s2, NumberOfCycles=3, s3...) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE CASE WHEN NumberOfCycles = 7 THEN s7 
           WHEN NumberOfCycles = 6 THEN s6 
           ...
      END IS NOT NULL
```

Never test for `<> NULL`.  Even NULL is not equal to NULL, and so that always returns true.

Comment: Doesn't "NULL <> NULL" resolves to being false?  Then same as "NULL = NULL" resolves to being false?

Comment: Apparently Access doesn't have a CASE statement

Comment: You can use IIF([NumberOfCycles = 7, [s7], IIF(NumberOfCycles = 6, [s6]), NULL)  It's messy or you could create a function in vba.

Comment: The Choose() and Switch() functions offer some alternatives. But any time I'm tempted to use either of them, it's a clue the data ought to be in a lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

A rough example using a Union query.

```
SELECT a.Cycle, a.NoCycles, a.CS, a.CSName 
FROM
    (SELECT c.Cycle, c.NoCycles, c.s1 As CS, "s1" As CSName
    FROM CycleTable c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Cycle, c.NoCycles, c.s2 As CS, "s2" As CSName
    FROM CycleTable c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Cycle, c.NoCycles, c.s3 As CS, "s3" As CSName
    FROM CycleTable c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Cycle, c.NoCycles, c.s4 As CS, "s4" As CSName
    FROM CycleTable c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Cycle, c.NoCycles, c.s5 As CS, "s5" As CSName
    FROM CycleTable c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Cycle, c.NoCycles, c.s6 As CS, "s6" As CSName
    FROM CycleTable c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Cycle, c.NoCycles, c.s7 As CS, "s7" As CSName
    FROM CycleTable c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Cycle, c.NoCycles, c.s8 As CS, "s8" As CSName
    FROM CycleTable c) a

WHERE a.Cycle=4 AND a.CSName="s4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agre with a comment, you should review the design for alternatives.

In terms of the existing design there appear to be two options to me...
1. Build up the query string in VBA, then execute it
2. Use a CASE statement in the WHERE clause

I admit I don't know Access's syntax, so here is SQL Server syntax for your inspiration...

```
WHERE
   CASE NumberOfCycles
      WHEN 1 THEN s1
      WHEN 2 THEN s2
      WHEN 3 THEN s3
      WHEN 4 THEN s4
   END
   IS NOT NULL
```

This, however, is not efficient as it is scanning every record and not able to make use of indexes, etc.

**EDIT**

Also, note that based on your example and actual question, if you ever have "NumberOfCycles = 3" but records where s3 and s4 are populated, both records are returned.

I believe you would be advised to have a field "cycle" which describes the cycle at which the data was populated.

```
   Cycle | Number Of Cycles | s1 | s2 | s3 | s4
      1  |                4 |  0 |  - |  - |  -
      2  |                4 |  0 |  1 |  - |  -
      3  |                4 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  -
      4  |                4 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1
```

Then you just need to search for "Cycle = NumberOfCycles"

**EDIT**

Apparently Access has a horrible SWITCH statement...

```
WHERE
   SWITCH(
      NumberOfCycles=1, s1,
      NumberOfCycles=2, s2,
      NumberOfCycles=3, s3,
      NumberOfCycles=4, s4
   )
   IS NOT NULL
```

Or you can expand to a horrible OR statement...

```
WHERE
   (NumberOfCycles=1 AND S1 IS NOT NULL)
OR (NumberOfCycles=2 AND S2 IS NOT NULL)
OR (NumberOfCycles=3 AND S3 IS NOT NULL)
OR (NumberOfCycles=4 AND S4 IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Case statement will only work on passthrough query to SQL Server, not in MS Access.